# Flutter Form Step and scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I have Flutter view with Form and Stepper widgets. Every Stepper have a lot of widgets inside. When I click on Step, screen is automatically scrolling to the end of new expanded Step. How to change scrolling to see top of expanded Step after click on it?

[image]

(When I click on STEP 2, STEP2 is expanded and I see last widgets from STEP2, not first widgets of STEP2)

Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int currentStep = 0;
  List<Step> generateSteps(int j) {
    List<Step> a = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
      a.add(Step(
          title: const Text("STEP"),
          content: Column(children: generateWidgets(10))));
    }
    return a;
  }

  List<Widget> generateWidgets(int j) {
    List<Widget> a = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
      a.addAll([
        Text("Field: $i"),
        TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Enter your email',
          ),
        ),
      ]);
    }
    return a;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Step> ft = generateSteps(6);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
            child: Stepper(
          currentStep: currentStep,
          onStepTapped: (int step) {
            setState(() {
              currentStep = step;
            });
          },
          steps: ft,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you put your code in please? cheers

Comment: Just added @James ;)

Comment: @James - any idea how to solve problem? I need focus on 1st element from currently opened step.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? Because we exactly have the same problem.

Comment: Hmmm, I do not remember, probably I find workaround. But what I can tell now? You can try focus on 1st element frm new step and do it asap after change Step